# How to optimize big result to sum in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a user consume history record table. Sometimes, the data is very big (> 1 million / day).

Now I have to calculate the table to get report data.

Here is the SQL:

```
    SELECT SUM(consume_num) AS consumeNum, SUM(transin_num) AS transinNum
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1
    END AS transinUserNum, SUM(transin_count) AS transinCount, SUM(transout_num) AS transoutNum
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT transout_user_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT transout_user_num) - 1
    END AS transoutUserNum, SUM(transout_count) AS transoutCount, SUM(send_amount) AS sendAmount
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT sender_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT sender_num) - 1
    END AS senderNum, SUM(send_num) AS sendNum, SUM(picked_amount) AS pickedAmount
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT picker_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT picker_num) - 1
    END AS pickerNum, SUM(picked_num) AS pickedNum, SUM(bumped_amount) AS bumpedAmount
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT bumper_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT bumper_num) - 1
    END AS bumperNum, SUM(bumped_num) AS bumpedNum, SUM(back_money_amount) AS backMoneyAmount
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN (
                'SEND_RED_ENVELOPE', 
                'BUMPED_SELF', 
                'LOCKED', 
                'HAPPY_RAIN_SEND', 
                'HAPPY_CARD_MATCH', 
                'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF', 
                'HAPPY_BOMB_SETTLEMENT_UNLOCK'
            ) THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS consume_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_IN') THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS transin_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_IN') THEN user_id
            ELSE -1
        END AS transin_user_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_IN') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS transin_count
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_OUT') THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS transout_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_OUT') THEN user_id
            ELSE -1
        END AS transout_user_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PLATFORM_OUT') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS transout_count
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('SEND_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_SEND') THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS send_amount
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('SEND_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_SEND') THEN user_id
            ELSE -1
        END AS sender_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('SEND_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_SEND') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS send_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PICK_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_PICK') THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS picked_amount
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PICK_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_PICK') THEN user_id
            ELSE -1
        END AS picker_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('PICK_RED_ENVELOPE', 'HAPPY_RAIN_PICK') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS picked_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('BUMPED_SELF', 'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF') THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS bumped_amount
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('BUMPED_SELF', 'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF') THEN user_id
            ELSE -1
        END AS bumper_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN ('BUMPED_SELF', 'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS bumped_num
        , CASE 
            WHEN consume_item IN (
                'RED_ENVELOPE_BACK', 
                'PICK_RED_ENVELOPE', 
                'BUMPED_OTHERS', 
                'TICK_WIN', 
                'REVOLVER_ABANDON_WIN', 
                'REVOLVER_GET_SHOT_WIN', 
                'REVOLVER_NOT_GET_SHOT_WIN', 
                'UNLOCKED', 
                'HAPPY_RAIN_BACK', 
                'HAPPY_CARD_SCRAPE'
            ) THEN ABS(consume_num)
            ELSE 0
        END AS back_money_amount
    FROM wallet_consume_record
    WHERE created_time < 1593359999999
    AND created_time >= 1593273600000
    AND app_id = 1
    AND tenant_id = 1
) a;
```

and I have already created an index on the `created_time` column.

This is the `EXPLAIN` plan:

```
+------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+
|   id | select_type   | table                 |   partitions | type   | possible_keys                   |    key |   key_len |    ref |     rows |   filtered | Extra       |
|------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+------------+-------------|
|    1 | SIMPLE        | wallet_consume_record |       <null> | ALL    | wallet_consume_created_time_idx | <null> |    <null> | <null> | 15624863 |         23 | Using where |
+------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.031s
```

Here is the dataset result:

```
mysql root@10.244.5.27:meow_report_pro> select count(*)
                                     -> from wallet_consume_record
                                     -> where created_time < 1593359999999
                                     -> AND created_time >= 1593273600000;
+------------+
|   count(*) |
|------------|
|    1876234 |
+------------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.403s
```

Now, the SQL takes 300s+ seconds to completely execute and always times out in my application query. is it possible to make the SQL better to get high performance?

This is my table structure:

```
mysql root@10.244.5.27:meow_report_pro> SHOW CREATE TABLE wallet_consume_record;
+-----------------------+----------------+
| Table                 | Create Table   |
|-----------------------+----------------|
| wallet_consume_record | CREATE TABLE `wallet_consume_record` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_play_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '<E6><88><BF><E9><97><B4><E6><A0><87><E8><AF><86>',
  `consume_num` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E6><B6><88><E8><B4><B9><E9><87><91><E9><A2><9D>',
  `consume_item` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '<E6><B6><88><E8><B4><B9><E9><A1><B9><E7><9B><AE>',
  `user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E7><94><A8><E6><88><B7><E6><A0><87><E8><AF><86>',
  `consume_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E6><B6><88><E8><B4><B9><E6><97><B6><E9><97><B4>',
  `description` varchar(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '<E6><B6><88><E8><B4><B9><E6><8F><8F><E8><BF><B0>',
  `trans_no` bigint(64) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E4><BA><A4><E6><98><93><E6><B5><81><E6><B0><B4><E5><8F><B7>',
  `remain_num` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E4><BA><A4><E6><98><93><E5><90><8E><E5><89><A9><E4><BD><99><E9><87><91><E9><A2><9D>',
  `current_num` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E4><BA><A4><E6><98><93><E5><89><8D><E8><B4><A6><E6><88><B7><E4><BD><99><E9><A2><9D>',
  `current_status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E5><BD><93><E5><89><8D><E4><BA><A4><E6><98><93><E7><8A><B6><E6><80><81><EF><BC><88>1<E3><80><81><E4><BA><A4><E6><98><93><E5><AE><8C><E6><88><90><EF><BC><89>',
  `pay_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '<E6><94><AF><E4><BB><98><E6><96><B9><E5><BC><8F>(1.<E5><B9><B3><E5><8F><B0><E5><85><85><E5><80><BC><E6><94><AF><E4><BB><98>)',
  `app_mark` varchar(128) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN' COMMENT '<E5><BA><94><E7><94><A8><E6><9E><9A><E4><B8><BE><E5><90><8D><E7><A7><B0>',
  `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E5><88><9B><E5><BB><BA><E6><97><B6><E9><97><B4>',
  `updated_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '<E6><9B><B4><E6><96><B0><E6><97><B6><E9><97><B4>',
  `device` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '<E8><AE><BE><E5><A4><87><E7><B1><BB><E5><9E><8B>',
  `app_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '<E5><BA><94><E7><94><A8><E6><A0><87><E8><AF><86>',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `trans_no` (`trans_no`),
  KEY `index_consume_num` (`consume_num`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_consume_time` (`consume_time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `wallet_consume_created_time_idx` (`created_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18925265 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='<E9><87><91><E9><A2><9D><E6><B6><88><E8><B4><B9><E6><98><8E><E7><BB><86>'                |
+-----------------------+----------------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.003s
```

by the way, the app_id only have 6 value: 1,2,3,4,5 and tenant_id only have 3 value 1,2,3 and consume_item have 10 value of string.

Comment: From your `EXPLAIN`, (`key`), no index is updated though your created index is possible. What portion of the table does the data range indicated correspond to? Do the range of `consume_item` values in the query represent the entire set? If no appending `consume_item` to the index may help. Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE wallet_consume_record` in your question. An instantaneous answer to looking at 1M rows may be asking too much. Your query looks like its trying to format the answer too much rather than just deliver the sums.

Comment: You may try to add another nesting if explain shows that the COUNTS are evaluated twice: `SELECT consumeNum, transinNum
     , CASE WHEN transinUserNum < 0 THEN 0 ELSE transinUserNum END AS transinUserNum
     , ...
FROM (     
    SELECT SUM(consume_num) AS consumeNum
         , SUM(transin_num) AS transinNum
         , COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1 as transinUserNum ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is narrow the search even further by making a decent covering index

Please create the following index

```
ALTER TABLE wallet_consume_record
    ADD INDEX everything_and_the_kitchen_sink_ndx
    (app_id,tenant_id,created_time,consume_num,consume_item,user_id)
;
```

This index will contain all the columns needed in the subquery. That way, all the needed data comes from the index and the table is never touched. Also note that I placed the columns `app_id` and `tenant_id` in the front of the index to narrow the search, which will minimize the range of `created_time`.

So, proceed to create this index, generate the EXPLAIN plan, and see if things improve.

Comment: I don't know why the consume_num should add a index. it is the user spent money value,it does not in the where clause. @RolandoMySQLDBA

Comment: Hey @Dolphin The extra columns (`consume_num`,`consume_item`,`user_id`) should be in the index so that mysqld does not need to consult the table for data. It will already be available when accessing the index. Good covering indexes can go beyond satisfying `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplifications**

```
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1 < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1
END AS transinUserNum
```

can be simplified to

```
GREATEST(COUNT(DISTINCT transin_user_num) - 1, 0)  AS transinUserNum
```

and...

```
CASE 
    WHEN consume_item IN ('BUMPED_SELF', 'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS bumped_num
```

to

```
consume_item IN ('BUMPED_SELF', 'HAPPY_RAIN_BUMPED_SELF')  AS bumped_num
```

The second one is because `true` and `false` is represented as 1 and `0`.

**Missing millisecond**

```
WHERE created_time < 1593359999999  -- use <=
```

**Better INDEX**

```
WHERE created_time <= 1593359999999
AND created_time   >= 1593273600000
AND app_id = 1
AND tenant_id = 1
```

needs

```
INDEX(tenant_id, app_id, created_time)
```

At the same time toss `index_tenant_id` because it will be redundant.